# Python Micro:bit Bitio Error - microbit.repl.repl.REPLException: Timeout trying to receive

Tags: python, bbc-microbit

I have a micro:bit (v1.3 B) and am trying to use the Python [bitio library](https://github.com/whaleygeek/bitio) on a MacBook (macOS Monterey). I've been following the [getting started section](https://github.com/whaleygeek/bitio#getting-started) and have gotten to the ['making a connection' section](https://github.com/whaleygeek/bitio#making-a-connection).

I've already 'flashed' the [bitio.hex](https://github.com/whaleygeek/bitio/blob/master/bitio.hex) file to the micro:bit by uploading the file, and it successfully shows the bitio logo, like shown [here](https://github.com/whaleygeek/bitio/blob/master/bitio.png).

When I run `python3 counter.py` it gives me the following error:

```
microbit.repl.repl.REPLException: Timeout trying to receive [
raw EPL; CTRL-B to exit
>]
```

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Downloads/bitio-master/src/counter.py", line 3, in <module>
    import microbit
  File "/Users/User/Downloads/bitio-master/src/microbit/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    repl.to_raw()
  File "/Users/User/Downloads/bitio-master/src/microbit/repl/repl.py", line 109, in to_raw
    self.wait_repl_response()
  File "/Users/User/Downloads/bitio-master/src/microbit/repl/repl.py", line 143, in wait_repl_response
    self.receive("\r\nraw REPL; CTRL-B to exit\r\n>", timeout=2)
  File "/Users/User/Downloads/bitio-master/src/microbit/repl/repl.py", line 82, in receive
    raise REPLException("Timeout trying to receive [%s]" % buffer)
microbit.repl.repl.REPLException: Timeout trying to receive [
raw EPL; CTRL-B to exit
>]
```

The full output:

```
User@Users-Macbook-Pro src % python3 counter.py
No micro:bit has previously been detected
Scanning for serial ports
remove device, then press ENTER
scanning...
found 137 device(s)
plug in device, then press ENTER
scanning...
found 138 device(s)
found 1 new device
selected:/dev/tty.usbmodem14202
Do you want this device to be remembered? (Y/N)Y
connecting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Downloads/bitio-master/src/counter.py", line 3, in <module>
    import microbit
  File "/Users/User/Downloads/bitio-master/src/microbit/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    repl.to_raw()
  File "/Users/User/Downloads/bitio-master/src/microbit/repl/repl.py", line 109, in to_raw
    self.wait_repl_response()
  File "/Users/User/Downloads/bitio-master/src/microbit/repl/repl.py", line 143, in wait_repl_response
    self.receive("\r\nraw REPL; CTRL-B to exit\r\n>", timeout=2)
  File "/Users/User/Downloads/bitio-master/src/microbit/repl/repl.py", line 82, in receive
    raise REPLException("Timeout trying to receive [%s]" % buffer)
microbit.repl.repl.REPLException: Timeout trying to receive [
raw EPL; CTRL-B to exit
>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue, turns out I had to give the terminal (or whatever editor/IDE used) full disk access in settings